# После установки Red Hat Linux ОС видит только четыре диска из шести

Tags: hdd, ssd, redhat

Недавно я установил Red Hat Enterprise Linux на компьютер, но почему-то операционная система (я имею в виду RHEL) видит только 4 диска из шести установленных на компьютере (3 HDD и 1 SSD). Один SSD и один HDD он не видит. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обойти это ограничение.

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0  55,5M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/2409
loop1    7:1    0  95,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/mpv/2
loop2    7:2    0     4K  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/bare/5
loop3    7:3    0  61,9M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core20/1434
loop4    7:4    0 152,4M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/skype/209
loop5    7:5    0 164,8M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/161
loop6    7:6    0 320,2M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/telegram-desktop/3975
loop7    7:7    0 111,7M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/13250
loop8    7:8    0  81,3M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1534
loop9    7:9    0 110,6M  1 loop /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/12834
sda      8:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 185,6G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   197G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0  89,9G  0 part /
├─sda4   8:4    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   4,4G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0   3,7T  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0   128M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   0   3,7T  0 part 
sdc      8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdc1   8:33   0   549M  0 part 
├─sdc2   8:34   0 341,6G  0 part 
├─sdc3   8:35   0   518M  0 part 
└─sdc4   8:36   0 588,9G  0 part 
sdd      8:48   0   1,8T  0 disk 
└─sdd1   8:49   0   1,8T  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

---

```
$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RX790 Host Bridge [1002:5957]
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port A) [1002:5978]
00:05.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RX780/RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port B) [1002:597b]
00:06.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RD790 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port C) [1002:597c]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] [1002:4390]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:12.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:13.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller [1002:439c]
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384]
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration [1022:1200]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map [1022:1201]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller [1022:1202]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control [1022:1203]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control [1022:1204]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] [10de:1c82] (rev a1)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0fb9] (rev a1)
02:00.0 SATA controller [0106]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1062 Serial ATA Controller [1b21:0612] (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
04:07.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3060 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R [1814:3060]
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136602/discussion-on-question-by-----red-hat-linux--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

похоже по какой-то причине драйвера на эти диски удалены из Red Hat Enterprise, поэтому поищите их на [ELRepo.org](http://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage)

Судя по выводу `lspci -nn` нам нужен драйвер на IDE Controller, вот эта строка:

```
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller [1002:439c]
```

теперь зная **Vendor:Device** ID что указаны в конце строки **1002:439c** можно найти нужный нам драйвер на странице [DeviceIDs](http://elrepo.org/tiki/DeviceIDs) которым по итогу окажется **kmod-pata**

Теперь следуя инструкции на главной странице [elrepo.org](http://elrepo.org/tiki/HomePage#Get_started) подключите нужный репозиторий и установите **kmod-pata** драйвер.